# blank browser in flutter web in the moment of hot reload

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

**At the moment I do the hot reload**, the browser remains blank and does not respond, I started modifying the service worker file and nothing (blank browser in flutter web in the moment of hot reload)

enter code here

```
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
   <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
          https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-performance.js"></script>

   

   <script>
      
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
      const firebaseConfig = {
         apiKey: "****",
         authDomain: "a***",
         projectId: "a***",
         storageBucket: "****",
         messagingSenderId: "**",
         appId: "****",
         measurementId: "***"
      };

      
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
     
      
   </script>
   <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```